# Doxygen not including C bit-field documentation

Tags: c, doxygen, bit-fields

I have several psuedo-register structures created in a C program and have used structs and unions to implement the fields and collect all of the registers together.

Every member, field, etc has documenting comments, but the produced documentation does not show the documentation for the bit-fields... How can I solve this so that their documentation is included in the output?

Example of my implementation (it's the bitNName comments that don't show):

```
/** This shows in documentation. */
union REG1 {
    int all;            /**< This shows in documentation. */
    struct REG1BITS {
        int bit1Name:1; /**< This is not in documentation. */
        int bit2Name:1; /**< This is not in documentation. */
    } bit;              /**< This shows in documentation. */
};

/** This shows in documentation. */
union REG3 {
    int all;            /**< This shows in documentation. */
    struct REG3BITS {
        int bit1Name:1; /**< This is not in documentation. */
        int bit2Name:1; /**< This is not in documentation. */
    } bit;              /**< This shows in documentation. */
};

/** This shows in documentation. */
extern struct ALLREGS {
    union REG1 reg1Name; /**< This shows in documentation. */
    union REG1 reg2Name; /**< This shows in documentation. */
    union REG3 reg3Namd; /**< This shows in documentation. */
} CollectedRegs;
```

UPDATE: Just thought maybe this is because the bit-field containing structs are all named bit - is this a conflict for doxygen?

Comment: Bitfields are supported by Doxygen. With doxygen version 1.8.4 I did not see the problem with your example (and a default config file). Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @doxygen Ah, Im on 1.8.3.1, guess I need to update so.

Comment: @doxygen this actually hasn't made any difference. ALL_REGS and REGn are documented under data structures and bit and all are documented as data fields on the union ref page (though not on the data fields page) but bitnName fields ar enot documented at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is remedied in more recent versions of doxygen :)